# JEditable: format number before edit

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I'm currently using JEditable to edit a table of numbers. I use javascript to format my numbers to the French standard, with a space every three digits (eg. 1234567 becomes 1 234 567). These spaces are represented by `&nbsp;`.

Hence if I click to edit the number `1 234 567` it will come as `1&nbsp;234&nbsp;567` in the textbox. Is there a way to add a callback to the JEditable click event so I can replace the spaces by blanks? I do it already the other way around when the edit is finished but I don't know if there is a callback for the `click` event.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use function as `data`parameter to alter content before it is edited. For example:

```
$(".edit").editable('http://example.com/save', {
    cancel: 'Cancel',
    submit: 'OK',
    data: function (value, settings) {
        return value.replace(/ /gi, '');
    } 
});
```

Comment: Wow, an answer from the creator himself! Thank you, it solved my problem.

Comment: Awesome!  Clear, concise answer.  Solved my issue in no time at all - perfect, thanks Mika!